# How to add lines to multiple following lines conditionally with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to add bullet points to the start of sub-bullet points.

For example, converting this text file:

```
*foo
  abc
  def
  ghi
*bar
  jkl mno
*hello world
  pqr stu
  vwxyz
```

Into this text file:

```
foo, abc
foo, def
foo, ghi
bar, jkl mno
hello world, pqr stu
hello world, vwxyz
```

This seems easy, and while I have had some ideas, I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` script:

```
awk '/^\*/{ pfx=substr($0, 2); next }{ print pfx","$0 }' file
```

The output:

```
foo,  abc
foo,  def
foo,  ghi
bar,  jkl mno
hello world,  pqr stu
hello world,  vwxyz
```